# construct a json in javax.json with list of values for a key

Tags: java, json

I need to construct a javax.json.JsonObject with following data,

```
{
 "name": "John",
 "age": 20,
 "interests": [ "Reading", "Mountain Biking", "Hacking" ]
}
```

Code for the same ?

Answer (score 1):

```
 JsonObject personObject = Json.createObjectBuilder()
                .add("name", "John")
                .add("age", 20)                
                .add("interests", 
                     Json.createArrayBuilder().add("Reading")
                                              .add("Mountain Biking")
                                              .add("Hacking")
                                              .build()
                    )
                .build();
```